# Connection String Decorating

Tags: c#, sql-server

I found myself in a situation where it is necessary to often decorate connection strings with some kind of metadata, like an extra DB Provider attribute, read it back, and remove the decoration without damaging original content.

Here is how it looks like:

```
        var cs = new MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder 
        { User = "dmitry", Password = "Password!" }
        .Build();

        Console.WriteLine(cs); // Password=Password!;User=dmitry;

        cs = cs.With("Provider", "MSSQL"); 
        Console.WriteLine(cs); // Provider=MSSQL;Password=Password!;User=dmitry;
        Console.WriteLine(cs["Provider"]); // MSSQL

        cs = cs.Excerpt("Provider"); // Password=Password!;User=dmitry;
        Console.WriteLine(cs);
```

Where custom MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder is:

```
public class MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    public string User { get; set; } = "sa";
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ConnectionString Build() =>
        ConnectionString.Empty
            .With("User", User ?? throw new InvalidOperationException())
            .With("Password", Password ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
}
```

And library code is:

```
public sealed class ConnectionString
{
    public static explicit operator ConnectionString(string text) => Parse(text);
    public static implicit operator string(ConnectionString connectionString) => connectionString.ToString();

    public static readonly ConnectionString Empty = new ConnectionString(ConnectionParameter.None);

    public static ConnectionString Parse(string text, string regex = "(?<name>[^=]+)=(?<value>[^;]);?") =>
        new ConnectionString(
            new Regex(regex ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(regex)))
                .Matches(text ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text)))
                .Select(m => new ConnectionParameter(m.Groups["name"].Value, m.Groups["value"].Value)));

    ConnectionString(IEnumerable<ConnectionParameter> parameters)
    {
        Parameters = parameters.ToArray(); 
    }

    IEnumerable<ConnectionParameter> Parameters { get; }

    public string this[string name] => Parameters
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper())?.Value;

    public ConnectionString With(string name, object value) =>
        new ConnectionString(Parameters
            .Prepend(new ConnectionParameter(name, $"{value}")));

    public ConnectionString Excerpt(string name) =>
        new ConnectionString(Enumerable.Concat(
            Parameters.TakeWhile(p => p.Name.ToUpper() != name.ToUpper()),                
            Parameters.SkipWhile(p => p.Name.ToUpper() != name.ToUpper()).Skip(1)));

    public override string ToString() => ToString("{0}={1};");

    public string ToString(string format) =>
        string.Join("", from p in Parameters
                        select string.Format(format, p.Name, p.Value));
}
```

And:

```
sealed class ConnectionParameter
{
    public static readonly ConnectionParameter[] None = new ConnectionParameter[0];

    internal ConnectionParameter(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        Value = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What struck me most are these lines:

> ```
> p.Name.ToUpper() != name.ToUpper()
> ```

I find it's always better to use the `Equals` overload that accepts a `StringComparer` and set it as a `readonly` field for the entire class rather then hoping you don't forget `ToUpper` everywhere.

---

This is a minor thing but I find that `Excerpt` should be called `Without` because it does not actually create an excerpt where you can say what you want to have but rather the other way around. The parameter says what should be excluded from the string. I also think it should take a `params string[]` argument.

---

> ```
> new Regex(regex ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(regex)))
> ```

I find `new`ing a `Regex` should be reserved for initializing a field. In a situation like here the static `Regex.Matches` would be more suitable - unless there is a reason why you chose `new` over the static method.

---

> ```
> public string ToString(string format) =>
> ```

This one I don't like. It's not a standard .net practice. If you want to use a formattable `ToString` then the class should implement the [`IFormattable` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx) correctly... or you should make this one private.

Besides having this helper method to just do

> ```
> ToString("{0}={1};")
> ```

is a little bit overengineered. How many of such formats do you have? A single `ToString()` would do too.

---

`ConnectionParameter` should be `ConnectionStringField` (or `Property`) to clearly communicate it belongs to a connection string.

---

I'm not sure if you know that there is already a [`SqlConnectionStringBuider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and most providers have their own implementations.

I prefer to write extensions against this type rather than parsing everything myself. It also validates the keys you use so you cannot use anything that isn't supported... well, unless it was your intention and a reason for the custom builder.

Comment: 1) I stylistically prefer something with smaller number of nested brackets – easier to read :)
2) Agree
3) Allows for cleaner syntax, I prefer monadic functions where possible
4) There were `ToString("{0}: {1}\n")` couple times, so would not like to embed such a dependency in a library code. `IFormattible` looks like overkill here, there is no need in localization, etc.
5) `ConnectionParameter` is an internal library class, not visible outside, so it could have shorter name just to be understandable in the context.
6) I work with my own device/component type connection strings actually.

Comment: @DmitryNogin having a [custom string](https://github.com/he-dev/Reusable/blob/master/Reusable.Core/TehCodez/SoftString.cs) for case insensitive and trimmed strings is an even greater time and life saver ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From a code review point of view I feel that the code isn't needed, as the functionality is already implemented by [DbConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).  The existing implementation provides additional functionality and will be more robust.

```
var dbConnectionStringBuilder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
dbConnectionStringBuilder.Add("User", "dmitry");
dbConnectionStringBuilder.Add("Password", "Password!");

Console.WriteLine(dbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

dbConnectionStringBuilder.Add("Provider", "MSSQL");

Console.WriteLine(dbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

dbConnectionStringBuilder.Remove("Provider");

Console.WriteLine(dbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
```

If you really must parse from and output the connection string in another format, perhaps it would be best to consider it a separate conversion task.  Let `DbConnectionStringBuilder` do it's job, and have a static `ConnectionStringConverter` class to handle custom formatting.

Comment: 1) let’s say we have “a=1” originally, I decorate it with “a=2”, then remove “a” back. I need an original string, while DbConnectionStringBuilder returns an empty string. 2) This class old, mutable, has an ugly way too wide API (ISP!).